# Pattern matching in htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a rewrite condition in an .htaccess file which is used to 'not' force specific URLs to use a HTTPS connection but it's matching erroneously on other URLs at present, here's the rewrite rule...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond !/go/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app\.ihasco\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And here's an example of the URL I want to match on in the 2nd line:

```
http://app.ihasco.co.uk/training/MTMwfG5pbmVmb3Vy/go/ST/bmF0aGFuQG5pbmVmb3VyLmNvLnVr
```

However line 2 seems to be matching on URLs like the following also:

```
http://app.ihasco.co.uk/client/login
```

and is subsequently failing to force them to HTTPS. What am I missing? :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the `RewriteCond` what to match `!/go/` against. Change the second line to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/go/ [NC]
```

Comment: Doh, couldn't see the wood for the trees! Thanks! :)